# RadPanelBar Drag And Drop

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radpanelbar

Is it possible to accomplish drag and drop on radpanelbar in ASP.NET like this and how?

```
RadPanelBar
 MyList1   ->RadPanelItem
  item1   -> nested RadPanelItem
  item2
 MyList2
  item3
  item4
```

to

```
RadPanelBar
  MyList1   ->RadPanelItem
     item1   -> nested RadPanelItem
     item2
     item3
  MyList2
     item3
     item4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now RadPanelBar doesnt support drag and drop...you could use RadTreeview and style the Treeview main node to a panel bar main bar look..

For RadTreeView drag and drop check the following documentation

```
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/functionality/draganddropnodes/defaultcs.aspx
```